# How to use NUnit 3 in VS2015RC

Tags: c#, nunit, portable-class-library, visual-studio-2015, nunit-3.0

Is it possible to use NUnit3 Beta in VS2015RC?

I've just created a new Library Project (Package) and added NUnit and created a simple test to show the errors I'm getting.

Does it have some dependency on an older version of the framework?

**project.json**

[image: Settings]

**Test Class**

[image: Errors]

**Update**
The [Release Notes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3025133) say:

> To work around this issue, follow these steps: Right-click the project
> in which the errors are reported in Solution Explorer, and then click
> Unload Project. Right-click again on the project in Solution Explorer,
> and then click Edit .
>
> Note In this command,  represents the actual project
> name. In the  entry at the top of the project file that
> has no Condition attribute, add the following:
>
> true
> Save and close the file. Right-click the project name in Solution
> Explorer, and then click Reload Project.

However I cannot get this to work, I just get more warnings and errors in my errors window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that you should use xUnit.net for now,

https://github.com/aspnet/Testing/issues/34

NUnit won't be ported unless someone steps in.

Comment: NUnit will support CoreCLR, see active issue  https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/575.